# Python string replace not working when reading csv property

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, replace

I'm trying to curate a CSV file by removing all the occurrences of `"` and `'` in any property. But I'm not allowed to replace values, even if I already did it in the `Python` console.

I'm doing this:

```
import csv

input_data = open("D:/data/demo.csv", encoding="utf8")
reader = csv.DictReader(input_data)
csv_columns = reader.fieldnames

f = open("D:/data/output.csv", 'w', encoding="utf8", newline='')

for line in reader:
    try:
        new_line = None
        for prop in line:
            cured_str = str(line[prop]).replace("\"", "").replace('"', '').replace('"', "'").replace('"', "\'")

            if new_line == None:
                new_line = cured_str
            else:
                new_line += ", " + cured_str

        f.write(new_line + "\n")

    except Exception as err:
        print("Error: ", err)

input_data.close()
f.close()
```

The code executes well, but if you check the value of `cured_str`, the `"` and `'` are never replaced. A value in the `line[prop]` is, for instance:

```
'I\\'m at Fazıl Bey\\'in @aaa in Rome, Italy '
```

The full `demo.csv` content is:

```
id,message_id,date,text,tags,tweet_lang,source,place,geom,retweets,tweet_favorites,photo_url,quoted_status_id,user_id,user_name,user_location,followers,friends,user_favorites,status,user_lang,latitude,longitude,text_translated_en,src_lang,src_accuracy,text_translated_en_parallel,up_filter,prediction,probability_0,probability_1
10,569282882658807808,2015-02-21 23:49:50,fav,,,Twitter for Android,,0101000055B79C93C406DACC43C2B834440,,,,,1567775498,eliovmek,,,,,,,41.024757,28.787008,,zu,92.0,Social fav,,0,0.9732880735563579,0.026711926443642064
11,651384744010252288,2015-10-06 13:13:19,"Is I'm at  she İlia? ",,,Foursquare,,0101000020E6100000B37CFA5B44063D4027A1D377277F4440,,,,,156044562,ajan34,,,,,,,40.99339197,29.02448058,,tr,98.0,"I'm at Fazıl Bey'in @aaa in Rome, Italy ",,0,0.9181253978980514,0.08187460210194858
11,651384744010252288,2015-10-06 13:13:19,"IsI'm at  she İlia? ",,,Foursquare,,0101000020E6100000B37CFA5B44063D4027A1D377277F4440,,,,,156044562,ajan34,,,,,,,40.99339197,29.02448058,,tr,98.0,"I'm at Fazıl Bey'in @aaa in Rome, Italy ",,0,0.9181253978980514,0.08187460210194858
11,651384744010252288,2015-10-06 13:13:19,"Is I'm at  she İlia? ",,,Foursquare,,0101000020E6100000B37CFA5B44063D4027A1D377277F4440,,,,,156044562,ajan34,,,,,,,40.99339197,29.02448058,,tr,98.0,"I'm at Fazıl Bey'in @aaa in Rome, Italy ",,0,0.9181253978980514,0.08187460210194858
11,651384744010252288,2015-10-06 13:13:19,"Is she İlia? ",,,Foursquare,,0101000020E6100000B37CFA5B44063D4027A1D377277F4440,,,,,156044562,ajan34,,,,,,,40.99339197,29.02448058,,tr,98.0,"I'm at Fazıl Bey'in @aaa in Rome, Italy ",,0,0.9181253978980514,0.08187460210194858
11,651384744010252288,2015-10-06 13:13:19,"Is she İlia? ",,,Foursquare,,0101000020E6100000B37CFA5B44063D4027A1D377277F4440,,,,,156044562,ajan34,,,,,,,40.99339197,29.02448058,,tr,98.0,"I'm at Fazıl Bey'in @aaa in Rome, Italy ",,0,0.9181253978980514,0.08187460210194858
11,651384744010252288,2015-10-06 13:13:19,"Is she İlia? ",,,Foursquare,,0101000020E6100000B37CFA5B44063D4027A1D377277F4440,,,,,156044562,ajan34,,,,,,,40.99339197,29.02448058,,tr,98.0,"I'm at Fazıl Bey'in @aaa in Rome, Italy ",,0,0.9181253978980514,0.08187460210194858
11,651384744010252288,2015-10-06 13:13:19,"Is she İlia? ",,,Foursquare,,0101000020E6100000B37CFA5B44063D4027A1D377277F4440,,,,,156044562,ajan34,,,,,,,40.99339197,29.02448058,,tr,98.0,"I'm at Fazıl Bey'in @aaa in Rome, Italy ",,0,0.9181253978980514,0.08187460210194858
11,651384744010252288,2015-10-06 13:13:19,"Is she İlia? ",,,Foursquare,,0101000020E6100000B37CFA5B44063D4027A1D377277F4440,,,,,156044562,ajan34,,,,,,,40.99339197,29.02448058,,tr,98.0,"I'm at Fazıl Bey'in @aaa in Rome, Italy ",,0,0.9181253978980514,0.08187460210194858
11,651384744010252288,2015-10-06 13:13:19,"Is she İlia? ",,,Foursquare,,0101000020E6100000B37CFA5B44063D4027A1D377277F4440,,,,,156044562,ajan34,,,,,,,40.99339197,29.02448058,,tr,98.0,"I'm at Fazıl Bey'in @aaa in Rome, Italy ",,0,0.9181253978980514,0.08187460210194858
```

PS: it works in a console, but not from the script.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "it works in a console, but not from the script" ? Those words do not explain what issue you are facing and they don't even make sense because a script often is run from a console.

Comment: This `.replace("\"", "").replace('"', '').replace('"', "'").replace('"', "\'")` is nothing but non sense: you try **4** times to replace the same character. After first replace, no *true* double quote (`"`) can be in the string - but right of left double quotation marks (`”“`) could remain. And anyway it does not make sense to remove field quotes from a csv file. What are you **really** trying to achieve here?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I understand completely, but you seem to make duplicated replacements with more calls to `.replace()` than necessary.

Here is a simplified version of your code:

```
import csv

with open('demo.csv') as in_file, open('out.csv', 'w', newline='') as out_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(in_file)
    writer = csv.DictWriter(out_file, fieldnames=reader.fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()

    for row in reader:
        new_row = {
            k: v.replace('"', '').replace("'", '').strip()
            for k, v in row.items()}
        writer.writerow(new_row)
```

With this code, starting from the input `demo.csv`

```
id,message_id,date,text,tags,tweet_lang,source,place,geom,retweets,tweet_favorites,photo_url,quoted_status_id,user_id,user_name,user_location,followers,friends,user_favorites,status,user_lang,latitude,longitude,text_translated_en,src_lang,src_accuracy,text_translated_en_parallel,up_filter,prediction,probability_0,probability_1
10,569282882658807808,2015-02-21 23:49:50,fav,,,Twitter for Android,,0101000055B79C93C406DACC43C2B834440,,,,,1567775498,eliovmek,,,,,,,41.024757,28.787008,,zu,92.0,Social fav,,0,0.9732880735563579,0.026711926443642064
11,651384744010252288,2015-10-06 13:13:19,"Is I'm at  she İlia? ",,,Foursquare,,0101000020E6100000B37CFA5B44063D4027A1D377277F4440,,,,,156044562,ajan34,,,,,,,40.99339197,29.02448058,,tr,98.0,"I'm at Fazıl Bey'in @aaa in Rome, Italy ",,0,0.9181253978980514,0.08187460210194858
11,651384744010252288,2015-10-06 13:13:19,"IsI'm at  she İlia? ",,,Foursquare,,0101000020E6100000B37CFA5B44063D4027A1D377277F4440,,,,,156044562,ajan34,,,,,,,40.99339197,29.02448058,,tr,98.0,"I'm at Fazıl Bey'in @aaa in Rome, Italy ",,0,0.9181253978980514,0.08187460210194858
```

we obtain the following `out.csv`:

```
id,message_id,date,text,tags,tweet_lang,source,place,geom,retweets,tweet_favorites,photo_url,quoted_status_id,user_id,user_name,user_location,followers,friends,user_favorites,status,user_lang,latitude,longitude,text_translated_en,src_lang,src_accuracy,text_translated_en_parallel,up_filter,prediction,probability_0,probability_1
10,569282882658807808,2015-02-21 23:49:50,fav,,,Twitter for Android,,0101000055B79C93C406DACC43C2B834440,,,,,1567775498,eliovmek,,,,,,,41.024757,28.787008,,zu,92.0,Social fav,,0,0.9732880735563579,0.026711926443642064
11,651384744010252288,2015-10-06 13:13:19,Is Im at  she İlia?,,,Foursquare,,0101000020E6100000B37CFA5B44063D4027A1D377277F4440,,,,,156044562,ajan34,,,,,,,40.99339197,29.02448058,,tr,98.0,"Im at Fazıl Beyin @aaa in Rome, Italy",,0,0.9181253978980514,0.08187460210194858
11,651384744010252288,2015-10-06 13:13:19,IsIm at  she İlia?,,,Foursquare,,0101000020E6100000B37CFA5B44063D4027A1D377277F4440,,,,,156044562,ajan34,,,,,,,40.99339197,29.02448058,,tr,98.0,"Im at Fazıl Beyin @aaa in Rome, Italy",,0,0.9181253978980514,0.08187460210194858
```

Is this what you are intending to do?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using:

```
line[prop] = ''.join(c for c in str(line[prop]) if c not in '"\'')
```

For some weird reason, anything else worked